# Python3 randrange giving same result

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

So I'm making a small text-game and one of the things I want to do is to get a random number from a range of variables.

For testing purposes I've written a code looks something like this:

```
slow_speed = random.randrange(10,25)
medium_speed = random.randrange(26, 50)
fast_speed = random.randrange(51, 75)

penalty_list = [slow_speed, medium_speed, fast_speed]

for i in range(3):
    for penalty in penalty_list:
        print(penalty)
```

The idea is that it would loop over the list 3 times and each time give a different random number for each range.

However, what happens is that I get the same 3 numbers looped 3 times. I figured it was because the seed(time on my computer) is the same when I invoke the function, so I've tried to add a time.sleep() and a random.seed() but that didn't help.

So how can I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: What are `slow_penalty`, `medium_penalty` and `fast_penalty`? They don't appear to be randomly generated

Comment: Thanks for that, I changed the question. The penalties were also rand.range functions, it's just I carelessly picked the wrong ones to put in the question.

Comment: `random.randrange()` returns an *integer*, not an object that'll change value each time you print it. Produce more integers (by calling `random.randrange()` again each time) if you need new values.

Comment: The numbers only random when they are first chosen. See [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the variable declarations inside the `for` loop. This way, random numbers are generated during each iteration. The following is probably what you are looking for:

```
import random

for i in range(3):
    slow_speed = random.randrange(10,25)
    medium_speed = random.randrange(26, 50)
    fast_speed = random.randrange(51, 75)
    penalty_list = [slow_speed, medium_speed, fast_speed]

    for penalty in penalty_list:
        print(penalty)
```

**Sample Output**

```
13
31
63
17
26
61
16
46
67
```

Answer (score 3):

Define your speeds as tuple ranges, and then call `random.randrange` on them.  Use `*` to unpack the arguments in the tuple pairs.

```
slow_speed = (10,25)
medium_speed = (26, 50)
fast_speed = (51, 75)

penalty_list = [slow_speed, medium_speed, fast_speed]

for i in range(3):
    for penalty in penalty_list:
        print(random.randrange(*penalty))

# Output:
17
43
59
11
38
61
24
35
54
```

Or do the whole thing as a list comprehension:

```
>>> [[random.randrange(*penalty) for penalty in penalty_list] for _ in range(3)]
[[21, 27, 73], [10, 47, 72], [10, 35, 55]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Think of using a typewriter, and having a monkey bang on the keys. Once the hammers have hit the ink tape and the letters have been imprinted on the paper, those letters are not going to change anymore. You can re-read the resulting gibberish on paper, but the gibberish will stay the same. If you want different gibberish, put more paper in the typewriter and have the monkey bang on the keys again.

`random.randrange()` is that monkey, and it returns you an `int` object; that's the paper. Printing those integers in a loop won't change the result, you'll need to go back and have `random.randrange()` bang on the keys *each time in the loop*:

```
for i in range(3):
    slow_speed = random.randrange(10,25)
    medium_speed = random.randrange(26, 50)
    fast_speed = random.randrange(51, 75)

    penalty_list = [slow_speed, medium_speed, fast_speed]

    for penalty in penalty_list:
        print(penalty)
```

Comment: Thank you for the awesome explanation!

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(3):
    slow_speed = random.randrange(10,25)
    medium_speed = random.randrange(26, 50)
    fast_speed = random.randrange(51, 75)
    penalty_list = [slow_speed, medium_speed, fast_speed]
    for penalty in penalty_list:
        print(penalty)
```

you do not generate random number in every loop, thats the reason.